# onsaveinstancestate only works once?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an app with two layouts (portrait and landscape). There are 4 int values I want to save so they don't get erased on rotation. For that, I call on save instance and then I recover the state on the onCreate method like this:

```
 private int operando1;
    private int operando2;
    private int operador;
    private int contadorIntentos;

    private String operadorTxt;
    private static final String CONTADOR_INTENTOS = "contadorIntentos";
    private static final String OPERANDO1 = "operando1";
    private static final String OPERANDO2 = "operando2";
    private static final String OPERADOR = "contadorIntentos";


    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(CONTADOR_INTENTOS, contadorIntentos);
        outState.putInt(OPERANDO1, operando1);
        outState.putInt(OPERANDO2, operando2);
        outState.putInt(OPERADOR, operador);

    }




 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_actividad_principal);
       //other random code
        Random generador = new java.util.Random();


        if (savedInstanceState != null){
            contadorIntentos = savedInstanceState.getInt(CONTADOR_INTENTOS);
            operando1 = savedInstanceState.getInt(OPERANDO1);
            operando2 = savedInstanceState.getInt(OPERANDO2);
            operador = savedInstanceState.getInt(OPERADOR);
        }else {
            contadorIntentos = 0;
            operando1 = generador.nextInt(1000);
            operando2 = generador.nextInt(1000);
            operador = generador.nextInt(4);
        }
```

Well, it turns out that it only saves the state once. after the first rotation (when it saves correctly) if I modify things and rotate again it recovers the state of the first rotation. It's like onsaveinstancestate only works once. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Because savedInstanceState isn't null in all of the subsequent rotations, you are never generating new numbers (ex: never calling this again: `operando1 = generador.nextInt(1000)`...etc...)

Comment: Yes, that's the expected behaviour. It should generate numbers only the first time, and the next ones it should use the numbers already generated.  What happens instead is that the first time it generates numbers, the second time it uses the saved ones, but if the counter goes up (in the code non included) then that change isn't logged.

Comment: No matter what you are doing in `//other random code`, you will override it with the savedInstanceStateFields. I'd recommend placing the `//other randomCode` after restoring state. It's a matter of the order you are doing things.

Comment: The modifications I want to save don't happen in //other random code , but out of the oncreate() method, in a button.